# Variable 'new' is not defined

Tags: python

```
phrase = input("Enter text to Cipher: ")
shift = int(input("Please enter shift: "))
encryption = input("Do you want to [E]ncrypt or [D]ecrypt?: ").upper

new_strs = []

for character in phrase:
    x = ord(character)
    if encryption == ("E"):
        new = x + shift
    if encryption == ("D"):
        new = x - shift

new_strs.append(chr(new))

print (("").join(new_strs))
```

The code works whenever I have it without the "if encryption = E/D" but it doesn't if I do.

This is the error message that is occuring.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python34\Doc\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    new_strs.append(chr(new))
NameError: name 'new' is not defined
```

Comment: try changing to `upper()` instead of `upper`. It's a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `new_strs.append(chr(new))` inside the `for` loop. And also you need to declare also that variable inside the for loop. It's all about the variable scope. If you put `new_strs.append(chr(new))` outside the for loop, python will look for a variable `new` outside the for loop, since you're assigning some values to the `new` variable only inside the for loop.

And again you have to assign an empty string to `new` variable which exists inside the for loop, so that the value of `new` present inside the `if` condition will be assigned to the variable `new` which exists outside the `if` but inside the `for`.

```
for character in phrase:
    x = ord(character)
    new = 0
    if encryption == ("E"):
        new = x + shift
    if encryption == ("D"):
        new = x - shift

    new_strs.append(chr(new))
```

Comment: This is a good correction, but it does not explain the error.

Comment: I cant seem to fix this new error that's occurring unfortunately it says " File "C:\Python34\Doc\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    new_strs.append(chr(new))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)"

Comment: sorry change `new=""` to `new = 0`

Comment: In suggested solution use `new=0` instead of `new=""`, that might solve the issue..

Comment: This will fix the Error, but the code will still be incorrect. The result will be `new = 0` in every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are encountering is that `new` is never being assigned. This is because `encryption == "E"` is False, and so is `encription == "F"`. The reason it is false is that encryption is a function! Try printing it out and you will see. It is `<function upper>`. Compare these two lines

```
encryption = input("Do you want to [E]ncrypt or [D]ecrypt?: ").upper
encryption = input("Do you want to [E]ncrypt or [D]ecrypt?: ").upper()
```

The second one is the correct one. This is the source of your problem.

There are other issues, as pointed out by other answers. Combining them here, and also adding a validity check for encryption, here is my complete solution.

```
phrase = input("Enter text to Cipher: ")
shift = int(input("Please enter shift: "))
encryption = input("Do you want to [E]ncrypt or [D]ecrypt?: ").upper()
if encryption not in ("E", "F"):
    raise ValueError("invalid encryption type: %r" % encryption)

new_strs = []

for character in phrase:
    x = ord(character)
    if encryption == "E":
        new = x + shift
    if encryption == "D":
        new = x - shift

    new_strs.append(chr(new))

print (("").join(new_strs))
```